# How to save multiple checkboxes in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-collection

I have created a blade (using Laravel Collective) with a multipe checkboxes:

```
 @foreach($subsc as $subsc)

      <div>
         {{Form::checkbox('checkbox['. $subsc->Scheme->Scheme_id .']', '1')}}
        {!! Form::label('SchemeName', $subsc->Scheme->Scheme_Name.$subsc->Scheme->Scheme_id, ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
      </div>

  @endforeach
```

Now I want to save each checked box in a table as the `scheme_id`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could use an array as name to make it easier and try something like this.

```
Form::checkbox('schemeIDS[]', $subsc->Scheme->Scheme_id, true);
// Parameters checkbox: name, value, checked
```

In the controller function use

```
$schemeIDS = $request->get('schemeIDS'); // get all the checked values as array

foreach($schemeIDS as $schemeID)
{
    // insert into the database
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How do i now get the value of the checked box. . I need to insert the scheme_id only in the table.

Comment: @Johann each `$schemeID` in the foreach loop should be a scheme_id. The array should only contain checked values. You simply call an insert query inside the foreach loop to insert the data to your database or you can achieve the same result by using the Eloquent ORM.